# Using OpenGL with Akka Actors: guaranteeing a single thread is used for a specific actor

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, opengl, akka

I have a Scala/Java OpenGL application in which I use the Akka framework. At the moment, my OpenGL thread is independent from the actor system so I can guarantee calls to OpenGL functions always come from a single thread. This is important, otherwise OpenGL will complain.

Until now, I had to send messages from the OpenGL thread to actors in the system and this works pretty well. I am now faced with the need to send messages the other way around, but of course I cannot simply put the OpenGL in an actor as this will break the requirement that it runs from a single thread.

An alternative would be to use a queue and a lock manually for the communication between actors and the OpenGL thread, but I'd like to know if there's a way to place OpenGL calls in a special Actor that would be given a guarantee by Akka to run in a single thread.

Regards

Comment: You can see [how this is done for Swing](https://gist.github.com/2941554) (which requires all rendering work happen in Event Dispatch Thread)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a single thread per actor using a `PinnedDispatcher`. According to the doc:

> This dispatcher dedicates a unique thread for each actor using it;
>   i.e. each actor will have its own thread pool with only one thread in
>   the pool.

Comment: Does it guarantee that this particular actor won't be running on any other thread, or also that this thread won't be used by any other actors? It might seem like a detail, but it might be significant in some cases...